# Should we have tags for part of the Tripitaka?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we have tags for parts and sub divisions of the Tripitaka and also the sutras?

E.g. Suthra Pitakaya, Anguthara Nikaya, etc.

Comment: What efficiency would this create?

Comment: We can search for all question with the particular tag. E.g. Say I want to read all question on Anapana Sutta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think yes. Because there are some suttas with same name but in different locations of the Tripitaka. So it is a good practice to add a tag or a reference. For example, I have seen 5 suttas named "Anuruddha sutta" in different parts of the Tripitaka.